# Pausing jscrollpanel and then unpausing [To stop scrollpane movement on tablet when pane has slider inside.]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I've read the jsscrollpane docs and seen the examples, but I can't find anything re:this.

Basically I have a regular JQuery slider in my scrollable area. As I drag it left to right / right to left on a tablet devices if my finger goes up or down the scroll area moves up or down.

I just want a way to temporarily lock JsScrollPane from working during the slide and then when finished unlock so it works again. It's got a great redraw feature which works in most cases I need but there doesn't seem to be a pause, stop, destroy feature for me to lock the pane when the scroller starts it's drag - and I want to keep it looking visually the same during the lock/unlock.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's not possible to do..

Thanks,
Dave